# eigenvalues of outer product matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, outer-product

Let $\mathbb R^m\ni \mathbf x \ne \mathbf 0 \ne \mathbf y\in\mathbb R^n$. Let $A = \mathbf x\mathbf y^T$ and find the single non-zero eigenvalues of $A$. Note the compact SVD of this matrix $A$ is

$$\left(\frac x {\|x\|}\right)\cdot (\|x\|\|y\|)\cdot \left(\frac {y^T} {\|y\|}\right) = (U_1)\cdot (S)\cdot(V_1).$$

Note the liberal use of parenthesis to avoid any ambiguity of what $U_1,S,V_1$ are.

Can I proceed similarly to this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403614/eigenvalues-of-outer-product-matrix-of-two-n-dimensional-vectors) to try and find the single $\lambda \ne 0$? See that $Au = xy^Tu = \lambda u$. Then we have $xy^Tu = \lambda u \implies y^Tx(y^Tu) = \lambda y^T u \implies \lambda = y^Tx \equiv  (\|y\|\|x\|)^2 \implies \sigma = \sqrt{\lambda} = \|y\|\|x\|$?

Comment: The non-zero eigenvalue of this matrix is equal to the dot-product $\mathbf y^T \mathbf x$, as you have found. It is not true that $y^Tx = (\|y\|\|x\|)^2$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, Ok I see, so then if $\lambda = y^Tx$, then how did we get a singular value of $\sigma = \|x\|y\|$?

Comment: What relationship do you expect to exist between the eigenvalues and singular values of $A$?

Comment: I'm sorry. I got confused. I think my question is answered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply $A x = x y^T x = (y^T x) x$ so $x$ is an eigenvector for eigenvalue $\lambda$.